# Creating a unit test for an ASP.NET MVC for an asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have an method which returns Task. I am trying to create a unit test for this method.

The return statement:
return View(await db.Devices.ToListAsync());

How do I create a test for this? Is there a tutorial on TDD with asynchronous methods?

Comment: you mean you're trying to test `db.Devices.ToListAsync()`?

Comment: Testing EF with async queries is mock intensive but not impossible. You have two option. Take the easier approach and abstract the db call behind something a little easier to mock or bite the bullet and mock the ToListAsync call to EF.  [Entity Framework Testing with a Mocking Framework (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx)